# html/css: use image-set to have a portrait or landscape image as background-image for a div

Tags: html, css, background-image, imageset

I'm trying to have a bootstrap 4 carousel use a landscape or portrait image as background for an item depending on the device orientation ...

following simplified code works somehow (with some style in the head) but I cannot find info on `image-set` so I do not know how to substitute `1x` and `2x` with `landscape` and `portrait` (or if that can be done):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"
         style="background-image: url('landscape.jpg');
                background-image: -webkit-image-set(
                  url('landscape.jpg') 1x,
                  url('portrait.jpg') 2x);
                background-image: -image-set(
                  url('landscape.jpg') 1x,
                  url('portrait.jpg') 2x)">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

did someone get something like this to work, or does someone have a better approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`image-set()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set()) doesn't support changing images based on any media condition. It just supports resolution and image type parameters.

An alternative would be to use regular media queries to change the background image of an element based on the [device orientation media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation).

An additional alternative would be using the [`<picture> element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture), through which you could specify different media conditions for different images via the [`media` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#the_media_attribute).

Comment: as mentioned it's finally a bootstrap carousel and within the programming I cannot easily define the image in css, it should be inline in the style property, i don't think the carousel supports <picture>

Comment: You can put whatever markup you want inside a Bootstrap carousel slide.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I did find the solution with your line of thinking ... I'll wait a moment if someone gives a complete answer (code examples) because answering my own is not satisfying to me ...

Answer (score 1):

I think, the way you are using the `image-set` is wrong. To be more precise the `image-set` is used to specify some diffrent quality images of the same picture.

As a solution i suggest that you use `background-size:cover` or something like that.

Comment: I already do but having certain images they are just wrong on a mobile, I should be having one image for portrait and one for landscape